# ci_reporter is unable to generate xml output

Tags: ruby, xml, jenkins, report

I have installed, Ruby 2.0.0 and Ruby 1.8.7, ci_reporter 1.8.4, test unit 2.5.4, rake 10.0.3 and pik to be able to switch between my 2 ruby versions.
I am using Jenkins 1.501 to make "automation test".

Here is my rakefile :

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/packagetask'
gem 'ci_reporter'
gem 'test-unit' 
require 'test/unit' 
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'  #http://juretta.com/log/2008/11/11/hudson_test_drive_part_1_rails/
require 'ci/reporter/rake/rspec'

task :test do
  ruby "test/test1.rb"
end
```

I saw that some people have solved this problem by changing :

```
require 'test/unit' 
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit' #http://juretta.com/log/2008/11/11/hudson_test_drive_part_1_rails/
```

by :

```
gem 'ci_reporter'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit_loader'
```

but it gives me an error.

I have the following file :

```
require 'test/unit'

class Test1 < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_add
    s = 4 + 1
    assert_equal(5, s)
  end

end
```

My Jenkins configuration is :

build --> execute windows batch cmd --> rake ci:setup:testunit test CI_REPORTS=results
post-action-build --> publish junit reports --> results/*.xml (here i have the following warning : `'results / *. xml' does not match anything: even 'results' not exist`)

Does the folder 'results' gets created by itself?

And finally my console output :

```
C:\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins TestLink Ruby\workspace>rake ci:setup:testunit test CI_REPORTS=reports 
rm -rf reports
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe test/test1.rb
Loaded suite test/test1
Started
.

Finished in 0.001 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed

1000.00 tests/s, 1000.00 assertions/s
Recording of test results
No test report file was not found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Publish the report of the results of JUnit tests' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

No folder results and no xml output.
Any ideas of what i should do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my probleme with this :

- Add the following requires to my test.rb : `require 'test/unit'`

  `require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit_loader'` 
  `gem 'test-unit'`
- Add the following require to my rakefile.rb : `require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'  #http://juretta.com/log/2008/11/11/hudson_test_drive_part_1_rails/`
- Execute with the cmd : `rake CI_REPORTS=reports test`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to answer your question about the reports directory, it should be created after the first successful run of your command. The warning is just Jenkins letting you know it doesn't exist at the time.

Second of all, I believe that the reason your CI report isn't being generated is because your `CI_REPORTS` environment variable is in the wrong place in the command: it should be at the beginning of the line, like

```
CI_REPORTS=reports rake ci:setup:testunit test
```

#### Update

This is causing the OP an error, despite it being valid in most shells. To achieve the same thing, export the environment variable as a separate command:

```
export CI_REPORTS=reports
rake ci:setup:testunit test
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, but no changes if a make : rake CI_REPORTS=results ci:setup:testunit test. Or build error if i put "CI_REPORTS=results rake ci:setup:testunit test"

Comment: I use windows7, so I created an environment variable CI_REPORTS with the value results. But no changes ^^

Comment: Sorry, that was obvious that you're using Windows but I blanked it out anyway :-P Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway Jonathan :) do you know another way to generate xml for ruby test?